# Using shape to get time complexity of loops, how?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am learning a video course about Data structure and Algorithm, and it says to use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM9Gf.png) shape to get the time complexity of this loop is O(n), which is quite confusing, need help

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
       //*** O(1)_operations;
```

here is the previous example, which use `i` and `j` as axis, to get the time complexity of it relevant loops(which is relatively clear)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a great place to use the big-O maxim

> When in doubt, work inside out!

That is, start with the most deeply nested loop, work out its complexity, and repeat until you’ve worked out the runtime.

Here, you have this code:

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
       //*** O(1)_operations;
```

So let’s begin with the inner loop. That loop runs i times and does O(1) work per iteration, so it does O(i) total work. Let’s replace the loop with something to that effect:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2) {
    // do O(i) work
}
```

The question now is how to work out what this loop does. Notice that i takes on the values 1, 2, 4, 8, …, until it reaches or exceeds n. In the worst case, that means the maximum value of i will be just around 2n (do you see why?). We’re also doing O(i) work per iteration, so the work done here will be (roughly)

> 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + … + 2n.

All we need to do now is figure out what this sums up to. There are a couple of ways to do this. One of them is to use a picture like the one you linked. Do you notice how it adds up a bunch of powers of two, and how the overall rectangle has an area that’s roughly equal to the next power of two? Indeed, the exact mathematical answer is

> 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + … + 2<sup>k</sup> = 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 1.

Can you see where this comes from in the picture?

In our case, we have that

> 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + … + 2n = 4n - 1,

so the total work done here is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 loops here, the first one goes from 1 to n (exclusive) with an exponential step.

This loop execututes `floor(log(2, n - 1)) = p` times. And for every iteration `i = 2^k`, where `k = 0..p` inclusive. Second loop executes `i` times for every `i`, so all we need to do is just sum up `2^k` for `k = 0..p`. This is geometric progression with multiplier `2`.

```
Sum = 2^0*(2^(p-1)-1)/(2-1) = 2^(p-1)-1 = 2^(floor(log(2, n-1)))-1
```

Since `a^(log(a, b)) = b`, we can say that `Sum = O(n)`

P.S. Regarding this shape. I guess, this shape represents a geometric progression and shows how many iterations we're performing for every `i`. The square of this shape is an overall number of operations performed.